# Isotope object list, objects broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

my objectlist is so initzialized:

```
$( function() {
    var $container = $('div.hikashop_products');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.hikashop_product',
        transformsEnabled : false,
        columnWidth: 27.3 + '%',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
});
```

i tried to solve this problem with this line *columnWidth: 27.3 + '%',*, but that's not solution.

At the start are objects true sorted:
[image: True product sort]

And if i scroll then i see my list is broken:http://prntscr.com/4iy7j2

What i do incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this same issue here: [Masonry.js – Items not moving vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316420/masonry-js-items-not-moving-vertically/25317547#25317547)

It has to do with the images, and when they load into the page.